# Iframe method of uploading file returning HTML tags in returned HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, iframe

I am using the iframe jquery method to upload a file to my server. My PHP file that processes the uploda returns a JSON string.
The returned data is coming back with HTML in the data (which I imagine Firefox is putting in). How can I stop this or just strip out the JSON?

```
function uploadFile() {
      $("#invoice_upload_form").submit();                                                                                        
      $('#invoice_upload_frame').on('load',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();                   
        if($(this).contents()[0].location.href.match($(this).parent('form').attr('action')))
        {
          var html_return = $(this).contents().find('html').html();
          //var json_return = JSON.parse(html_return);
          alert(html_return);
          //alert(json_return);                                        
        }
      });
    }
```

Comes back as:

```
<head><link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource://gre-resources/plaintext.css" title="Wrap Long Lines"></head><body><pre>{"success":false,"message":"Error importing invoice file"}</pre></body>
```

Comment: use .text() instead of .html() would work

Comment: Probably be helpful to see the PHP file that's processing your upload, as well.

Comment: @mplungjan- Thankyou that worked! You should put it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.